Customizing `defineCollection` in Astro
Situation
I have a website with some bilingual MDX pages. My preferred way to organize my files is to have everything related to one "entry" in a single folder:
- blog
  - 01
    - index.th.mdx // maps to /blog/01
    - index.en.mdx // maps to /en/blog/01
  - 02
    - index.th.mdx // maps to /blog/02; /en/blog/02 will redirect to /blog/02

I tried to do this by manipulating getStaticPaths function so it parses which slug each entry should be mapped to.
Challenges
This works ok-ish. But this will result in 3 entries:

/blog/01/indexth
/blog/01/indexen
/blog/02/indexth

So when I want to list all the blogs, for example, I need to filter things out manually. In addition, when I try to use reference, referencing blog/01 (which is natural) doesn't work.
What I think I need
I need collection to look like:
entries: [
  {
    id: 'blog/01',
    th: { ... },
    en: { ... },
  },
  {
    id: 'blog/02',
    th: { ... },
    en: null
  },
}

So that when I query the collection I'd get the "correct" number of collections. I can deal with getStaticPaths from this manually.
What I've tried
I tried creating a custom loader... basically looking at Astro's code for glob and copy that... but then some methods are private and I can't build.
Another option I thought of is to create two collections—one for each language. But then it would be a bit more work querying both entries and reconcile them.
So I'm here asking if there's a better way to do this. Basically I need to

Intercept the results from getCollection, do some manipulation, and pass it along. I need to do this at the level which reference in Content Collection would also get this result as well; or
Modify the store after the default glob's loader gets called.

